# Qt <codecvt> : No such file directory

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I cant use `std::wstring_convert` in Qt 5.1, because it said me that `<codecvt>` : No such file directory. What can I do? I don't know... this code is working at the MSVC 2013.

Comment: That has nothing to do with Qt, that header file is part of the standard library that usually comes with your compiler and not Qt.

Comment: I use Qt Creator for GUI. Is not Qt Creator should include a standard c++ library(std::)?

Comment: If you use Qt Creator it probably comes with a version of GCC and its libstdc++ (the GCC variant of the C++ standard library). You have to make sure that version is new enough to handle C++11, *and* make sure that the `-std=c++11` flag is set when building.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: there is mingw and msvc versions. You can see that by checking out the download page.

Comment: "Is not Qt Creator should include a standard c++ library(std::)" The creator is just an IDE. The error comes from the compiler, *not* from the IDE. This has nothing much to do with Qt.

Answer (score 0):

QtCreator is just a front-end that allows you to edit your source files, it does not contain a compiler. On Windows you need either MinGW or Visual Studio to compile code.

If you want to use Qt 5.1 with Visual Studio 2013, you would have to compile Qt yourself. Digia provides builds for Visual Studio 2010 and 2012. You can find the latest version of Qt [here](http://qt-project.org/downloads) or an old release [here](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/).

My advice would be to install Visual Studio 2012 and download a VS2012 build of Qt. Then go to Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits, click the Add button on the right (or modify the existing one as it probably won't work anyway). Set the compiler to "Microsoft Visual C++ compiler 11.0 (amd64)" if you downloaded the 64 bit version of Qt or "(x86)" if you downloaded the 32 bit version.

Then set the debugger to cdb.exe and the Qt version to the one you just downloaded (if you don't see it, go to the Qt Versions tab at the top, add it, click Apply and the go back to Kits and it should be there). Click ok and your kit should be ready! Make sure that you don't have a warning signal that would point out a potential mistake.

Now open your project and go to the Projects tab (Ctrl + 5) and make sure your project is using the correct Kit.

You should now be all set up properly.

Additionally, if you don't want to install Visual Studio 2012 and want (or have to) work with VS 2013, you can use the Qt 5.3 *BETA* builds located [here](http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.0-beta/). Please note that these builds are in beta and shouldn't be used in production code, if you want to use VS2013 with Qt in production code I would recommend to build Qt 5.2.1 with VS2013, it's not that hard but it can take a while.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing this in your project file:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

You need to make sure that your GCC version (brought to you by mingw) supports that feature though. It is possible that you are using an old version where it was not supported.